# Send data to current php file from js script

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a php file, content.php, that is currently being loaded in the browser:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Content</title>

        <script src="content.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
            if ( isset($_POST["status"]) && ($_POST["status"] === 1) ) {
        ?>

            Content for users with status 1

        <?php
            } else {
        ?>

            Content for users with different status

        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I want to do, is set the

```
$_POST["status"]
```

variable from within

```
content.js
```

I have thought about using a hidden html form and clicking the submit button through javascript, but that doesn't really seem like an elegant solution.

I have also thought about using an XMLHttpRequest, the problem being that I haven't found a way to send the data to the currently viewed/loading page through an XMLHttpRequest.

I am using no extra libraries, only javascript and php.

Is there a more elegant solution to my problem the a hidden html form?

Comment: Change it based on what? This really sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Why don't you just use session values to set status?

Comment: Define ***elegant solution***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need to work with AJAX because you need to execute server side script in hidden manner and update the html.

1. `interface.php` has `content.js` and a `div`
2. `content.js` send ajax post request with `status`
3. `content.php` sends the content according to `status`
4. `interface.php`'s `div` is updated.

Here are the `content.js` and `interface.php`

```js
let status = 1;
loadDoc(status);

function loadDoc(status) {
  let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =
      xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "content.php", true);
  xhttp.send("status=" + status);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Content</title>
        <script src="content.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
       <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is your `content.php`

```
<?php
    if ( isset($_POST["status"]) && ($_POST["status"] === 1) ) {
?>

    Content for users with status 1

<?php
    } else {
?>

    Content for users with different status

<?php
    }
?>
```

Bingo! You set the `$_POST["status"]` via `content.js`

Answer (score 0):

POST variables can only be passed in a request header. This means that it has to be either a form submission, as you already know, or an AJAX request. There is no way to have a separate client-side resource supply new information to an existing request.